# MKAnnotationView RightCallOut button crashes my app when I click on it

Tags: garbage-collection, xamarin.ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I'm calling a service and returning a bunch of latitudes and longitudes which I'm then placing on a map using MapKit.

using MKAnnotationView I'm adding a RightCallOutButton to each annotation.

So I had to create a new MapDelegate.  Code below.

If I click on the button I create the app crashes and I get an error from MonoTouch saying the selector is accings omething that has already been GC'd (garbage collected).

So my question would be, where should I set the RightCalloutAccessoryView and where should I create the button, if not in this code below?

```
public class MapDelegage : MKMapViewDelegate {

     protected string _annotationIdentifier = "BasicAnnotation";
     public override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation (MKMapView mapView,                           NSObject annotation) {

MKAnnotationView annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(this._annotationIdentifier);


if(annotationView == null) {
     annotationView = new MKPinAnnotationView(annotation, this._annotationIdentifier);
}  else {
    annotationView.Annotation = annotation;
}


annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;
(annotationView as MKPinAnnotationView).AnimatesDrop = true;    
(annotationView as MKPinAnnotationView).PinColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.Green;
annotationView.Selected = true;    
var button = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
new UIAlertView("Testing", "Testing Message", null, "Close", null).Show ();
} ;

annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = button;
return annotationView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
annotationView = new MKPinAnnotationView(annotation, this._annotationIdentifier);
...
var button = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
```

You should avoid declaring local variables to hold references you expect to outlive the method itself. Once there's no reference to `annotationView` or `button` the Garbage Collector (GC) is free to collect them (the managed part) even if it's *native* counterparts still exists. However when a callback to them is called you'll get a crash.

The easiest solution is to keep a list of them and (at the class level, i.e. a `List<MKPinAnnotationView>` field) clear the list when you destroy the view. The `UIButton` should not be necessary since there's a reference between the view and it.

**NOTE:** work is being done to *hide* this complexity from developers in future versions of MonoTouch. Sadly you cannot ignore such issues at the moment.

Comment: so I would create a List<> within my MapDelegate class?  Not sure what you mean by clear the list when I destroy the view.  Where exactly am I adding the PInAnnotations?  I thought GetViewForAnnotation just handled one annotation at a time?

Comment: Okay I think i understand, and I got it to work.  I created the List and added the annoationView's to the list.  Do I need to worry about the List i created or will that get destroyed by the GC at some point?

Comment: It will be done, by the GC, once there's no more reference to the field's parent instance, but since it could grow large you would be better to ensure the 'parent' is being Dispose'd as soon as possible. You may also want to clear it manually if you hide/show the view (or keep it cached and clear it only when you receive a low-memory warning from iOS).

Comment: awesome thanks.  I got it.  Now I just need to figure out how to get my detailbutton to access the NavigationController lol for everything I figure out, there's 50 other things I need to learn :)